# Fast response for subset queries

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures

I have a database of 10,000 vector of integers ranging from 1 to 1,000. The length of each vector can be up to 1,000. For example, it can look like this:

```
vec1: 1 2 56 78
vec2: 23 34 35 36 37 38
vec3: 1 2 3 4 5 7
vec4: 2 3 4 6 100
...
vec10000: 13 234
```

Now, I want to store this database in a way that is fast in response to a particular type of request. Each request will come in the form of an integer vector, up to 10,000 long:

```
query: 1 2 3 4 5 7 56 78 100
```

The response should be the indices of the vectors that are subsets of this query string. For example, in the above list, only `vec1` and `vec3` are subsets of the query, so the response in this case should be

```
response: 1 3
```

This database is not going to change so you can preprocess it in any possible way. You may specify that queries come in any protocol as well, as long as the information is the same. For example, it can come as a sorted list or a boolean table.

What is the best strategy to encode the database and the query to achieve the highest response rate possible?

Comment: What can be the content of any vector, ie. the max number in a vector?

Comment: @vish4071 "integers ranging from 1 to 1,000" -- that is the alphabet in both the database and the queries.

Comment: Are vector contents unique?  I.e. can they be stored as sets?

Comment: @wflynny Absolutely. You can think of them as sets as repeated elements are treated as just one.

Comment: Is this a Python question or a database question? Do you want to know how to structure a database so that it can be queried (with SQL, for example) and return the indices of subset vectors, or are you wondering how to structure the data you described in Python?

Comment: @dave Sorry, the python tag was suggested by stackoverflow. You can write it in any language as long as you can explain the algorithm/data-structure.

Comment: @trVoldemort, look-up the algorithm I have suggested. It actually uses the python tag. For any other language, you would need implementation with modular arithmetic and all.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using python, this method seems easy. (For any other language also, it is implementable but will include modular arithmetic etc.)

So, for each number from 1-1000, assign a prime number to it. So,

```
1 => 2
2 => 3
3 => 5
4 => 7
...
...
25 => 97
...
...
1000 => 7919
```

For every set, use its value to be the hash function generated by product of all values in the set.

eg. If your vector, vec-x = {1,2,5,25}, vec-x = 2 * 3 * 11 * 97

Similarly, your query vector can be calculated as above. Let its value be Q.

If Q % vec-i == 0, it is a subset, else not.

Comment: Thanks! Come to think about it. How about instead of using prime numbers and multiplication, I use bits and `and` operations (`and not` to be exact)?

Comment: how would that help. I didn't get your method with bits.

Comment: It's almost the same as your method. For the preprocessing, convert a vector of integers into one single large integer. In binary this integer will have 1's at those locations specified by the vector. (e.g., [1 2 5] will become 1011, which is 19 in decimal.)

Comment: And we do the same for the query, converting it into a large integer with specific locations having 1's and the rest having 0's.

Comment: When it comes to confirming whether `A` is a subset of `B`, simply do `A and (not B)`. If this value is not 0 then `A` is not a subset of `B`.

Comment: @trVoldemort yes...this is actually a good method. Post it as answer if u want.

Comment: Since the question is about optimizing performance, it might also be worthwhile to pre-calculate the min, max, and length of all vectors. Since any vector with length greater than the query, or min / max outside the query min-max range cannot be a subset, you could (in many cases) substantially reduce the search space by first comparing summary statistics, then apply one of the methodologies suggested above to determine the actual subsets.

Comment: I have a question about the prime number approach. Assuming a vector contains all possible values (1 - 1000), then the product of corresponding primes would be a very, very large number -- something on the order of 10^3393. Does this present problems for storage of the hash?

Comment: @apollo2020, In python, numbers of this order are not a problem at all. And if you are working in any other language, you just need to use modular arithmetic concepts, keeping it all within `int` range.

Answer (score 1):

What about just preprocessing your vector list into an indicator matrix and using matrix multiplication, something like:

```py
import numpy as np

# generate 10000 random vectors with length in [0-1000]
# and elements in [0-1000]
vectors = [np.random.randint(1000, size=n)
           for n in np.random.randint(1000, size=10000)]

# generate indicator matrix
database = np.zeros((10000, 1000), dtype='int8')
for i, vector in enumerate(vectors):
    database[i, vector] = 1
lengths = database.sum(axis=1)

def query(ints):
    tmp = np.zeros(1000, dtype='int8')
    tmp[ints] = 1
    return np.where(database.dot(tmp) == lengths)[0]
```

The dot product of a database row and the transformed query will be equal to the number of elements of the row that are in the query.  If this number is equal to total number of elements in the row, then we've found a subset.  Note that this uses 0-based indexing.

Here's this revised for your example data

```py
vectors = [[1, 2, 56, 78],
           [23, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38],
           [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7],
           [2, 3, 4, 6, 100],
           [13, 234]]
database = np.zeros((5, 1000), dtype='int8')
for i, vector in enumerate(vectors):
    database[i, vector] = 1
lengths = database.sum(axis=1)

print query([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 56, 78, 100])
# [0, 2] 0-based indexing
```